# jQuery.extend() deep copy not working as I expected?

Tags: jquery, extends

I was testing deep copy with jQuery, and I got an empty object instead the right copy.

But the function `loop2` does the copy as expected (passed as reference).

But would not `loop` also get the reference of the extended / merged object too?

Why is it not passing correcty?

```
var obj1 = { hello: { f: 1 } };
var obj2 = {};

function loop(original, copy) {
    copy = $.extend(true, {}, original);
    console.log(copy);
}

function loop2(original, copy) {
    $.extend(true, copy, original);
    console.log(copy);
}

function run() {
    loop(obj1, obj2);
    console.log(obj2);

    loop2(obj1, obj2);
    console.log(obj2);
}
```

***output:***

```
Object {hello: Object}
Object {}  ---> why this one did not get the correct content?
Object {hello: Object}
Object {hello: Object}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in loop function you are creating new object and assigning it to local variable inside function scope. Global variable and object associated with it are not modified. This behavior is not connected to [`jQuery.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and will work the same without it:

```
var obj2 = {};

function loop(copy) {
  copy = 'a'; //new value assigned, not its reference
  console.log(copy); //a
}

loop(obj2);
console.log('->', obj2); //{}
//it is OK. Its reference was not touched

function loop2(copy) {
  copy.a = 'a'; //added a new property to its reference
  console.log(copy); //{ a: 'a' }
}

loop2(obj2);
console.log('->', obj2); //{ a: 'a' }
//it is OK. Its reference was touched
```

Comment: I see. But its weird. Because of how the link between variable name and its reference is created? I could think that if var a={test:1}, then the thing "var a" will be linked to the reference xyz... So when on the loop function i pass the argument copy as reference of var a, no matter that in the loop scope the copy arg is  assigned a new reference, because logical would think that it would mutate the reference, and now var a is assigned to that new reference